# UIViewcontroller is not presented in correct orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am presenting a view controller from another view controller using `presentViewController`.

The presenting view controller (The "SourceViewController") creates the new view controller and assigns it to a navigation controller before presentation (because the "NextViewController" wants a navigation bar and navigation controller).

```
// from the source view controller
@implementation SourceViewController

-(void)showNextViewController
{
NextViewController *viewController = [[NextViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
@end


@implementation NextViewController
// in NextViewController

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

But when I present the view controller when the originating view controller is in landscape the "NextViewController" isn't presented in portrait but rather in landscape like the source view controller.

I've tried many combinations of rotation methods but haven't been able to get it to present in the correct orientation.

I assume that it is possible because many apple components like UIImagePickerController are always presented in portrait , so how do I force its orientation?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

I've created a `UINavigationController` sub class:

```
PortraitNavigationController : UINavigationController

@implementation

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end
```

and then when presenting the `NextViewController`

```
PortraitNavigationController *nav = [PortraitNavigationController initWithRootViewController:nextViewController];

[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

and now `NextViewController` is indeed in portrait - but when I rotate the device to use this view controller and eventually dismiss it - the underlying source view controller looks all messed up.

The underlying view controller is a custom container view controller which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`

The containers it uses to display the child view controllers are not in their correct places

I don't want the container view controller to rotate at all as soon as the `NextViewController` is displayed and dismissed.

Comment: don't forget to implement supportedInterfaceOrientations to return a mask of the supported orientations.

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate your device the presented view controller is asked about the rotations and orientations it supports - In your case it's a UINavigationController and not an instance of NextViewController.  One way to fix this is to subclass UINavigationController and override the rotation methods and forward the calls onto it's root view.

As a side not UIImagePickerController is a subclass of UINavigationController.  It might make more sense to make NexViewController a subclass of UINavigationController and then inside that subclass initialize it with the correct root view controller.

Another option is to just alloc and init a UINavigationBar inside of NextViewController and add it as a subview if you don't need to use the navigation controller for anything.  In this case autolayout comes in handy because you can pin it to the top, left, and right and let it figure out the correct size and location for it.

Comment: So NextViewController should be "NextViewController : UINavigationController" and then create a private view controller? What happens if "NextViewController" is added to a NavigationController?

Comment: Thanks for the help -  I tried the subclass solution and added an editional edit if you have an idea of how to solve that problem

Comment: You'll need to do the same sort of circus with the view controller that does the presenting.  When your view controller is dismissed your original view controller is OK being in the same orientation so it doesn't rotate back to where you want it to be. Either provide layout code to support both orientations (a strength of autolayout) or add the relevant orientation code.